# How to select a calculated value including parameter using Zend FW?

Tags: zend-framework

I'm using Zend FW and have a select with specified columns to be selected, e.g.

```
$select = $this->_db->select();
$select->from( array("t" => 'table'), array( 'id', 'name', 'some_number'));
```

Now I want to get the `some_number` value multiplied by some given parameter, like :

```
select id, name, (some_number * $param) from table;
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, using `Zend_Db_Expr`. If someone else needs... That works for me:

```
$select->from( array("t" => 'table'), 
               array( 'id', 'name', 'new_number' => new Zend_Db_Expr('some_number * ' . $param ) )
             );
```